# Google Analytics Goal Regular Expression

Tags: google-analytics

I realized today that my Goal was set up for Exact Match of my Goal URL:

i.e. /purchase/thank-you.page

I set up the Goal URL to be Regular expression, as I looked into my Analytics and found that the actual URLs look something like:

/purchase/thank-you.page?purchaseID=xxxxxxx?transactionID=xxxx

Am I going to be safe just setting the URL goal type to Regular Expression and leaving the URL as: /purchase/thank-you.page?

Is that sufficient to capture everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use correct regex rules to properly match the strings, so this includes escaping special characters, and making sure your expression encompasses your desired strings accurately:

```
^\/purchase\/thank\-you\.page\?.*
```

So something like the above regex would capture everything beginning with `/purchase/thank-you.page?`

Comment: That helped. With the "verify this goal" link Analytics provide, my numbers are already looking up. Thank you.